# How can I generate a nonexistent identifier in an array?

Tags: php, performance, unique, uuid, combinatorics

I want to generate a unique value with a length of 12 characters. To generate unique values, I use this method:

```
function generate_unique_id()
{
    $time = substr(time(), -7);
    $month = mb_strtolower(date("M"));
    $symbol = "OM";
    $string = $month."".$time."".$symbol;
    $result = str_shuffle($string);
    return $result;
}
```

I tested this code to generate 30,000 unique values, but each time the loop is exited without generating the required unique identifiers.

```
$array = [];

for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    $unique_id = generate_unique_id();
    if(in_array($unique_id, $array)){
        echo $i;
        break;
    }
    $array[] = $unique_id;
}
```

How can I know the number of generated unique values with a length of 12 character strings and quickly generate a unique value if the generation capability has not reached the maximum number limit.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Comment: Why don't you use `bin2hex(random_bytes(6))` instead of a function like that?

Comment: Regarding *I want to generate a unique value with a length of 12 characters*:Why not just count? (00001-30000 just needs 5 chars, if you really need 12 just prepend a prefix), that way they'd be truly unique atleast.

Comment: Now I tested `bin2hex(random_bytes(6));` for generate `20000` unique id's. First time loop break with 9405 uuid, second time with 14793. I want generate all needed uuid in one time or in one looping @Script47

Comment: Instead of breaking, why not just regenerate the ID in the same loop?

Comment: I want generate uuid with my function or like to it with 12 length symbols(with letters and numbers) @ccKep

Comment: Instead of break generating in loop i used `continue` and given error `Maximum execution time`. But I must generate uuid faster then 30 sec. How I can generate faster uuid? @Script47

Comment: This `$time = substr(time(), -7);` is obviously flawed. You will get the same 7 numbers a few times a month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below generated *30,000* unique IDs in *21.378324985504*<sup>1</sup> seconds.

```
$ids = [];

while (count($ids) < 30000) {
  $id = bin2hex(random_bytes(6));

  if (!in_array($id, $ids)) array_push($ids, $id);
}

var_dump(count($ids));
var_dump($ids);
```

The code above will continue generating IDs until it gets 30,000 unique IDs, there is no reason to `break`.

<sup>1</sup>Generation time may vary.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/CooperativePrudentRegression)

**Update #1**

For those that don't have PHP 7 available, you can use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) function.

**Update #2**

This snippet is massively more efficient, as per [@cckep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179287/cckep) comment:

```
$time_start = microtime(true); 
$ids = [];

while (count($ids) < 30000) {
  $id = bin2hex(random_bytes(6));

  if (!isset($ids[$id])) $ids[$id] = true;
}

$ids = array_keys($ids);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);

var_dump(count($ids));
var_dump($ids);

echo $execution_time;
```

Comment: @ccKep I would imagine that after generating 30k unique ids you'd want to store them and keep referencing that one set... at least, I hope so...

Comment: Using `in_array` really slows this solution down, take a look at [this](https://repl.it/repls/PrizeDefiniteApache) approach (basically the same thing, just using the generated IDs as array keys), bringing the generation time down from ~25s to <1s.

Comment: Your last updated code (Update 2) has potential to return duplicates, you're only checking if the newly generated id is equal to the last generated. For testing purposes: Replace `random_bytes(6)` with `random_bytes(2)` (meaning potential values of 0000 to ffff, meaning 65536 possible values) and let it generate 30000 values, `array_unique` them  and you will nearly always receive <30k results. I understand the probability of that happening with 6 bytes is abysmal - but it's not the intended goal to have duplicates.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to bash your answer - I like this approach a lot more than my posted answer. Just with the addition of using array keys instead of `in_array`.

Comment: @ccKep I've updated my answer to what your link reflected earlier. Thank you for the feedback and don't worry, I welcome constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, should work though (random prefix + hex-counter suffix):

```
<?php

function unique_id($length = 12)
{
    static $counter = 0;
    $suffix = dechex($counter);
    $prefixLen = $length - strlen($suffix);
    $prefix = substr(uniqid(), -$prefixLen);
    $counter++;
    return $prefix.$suffix;
}

$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 30000; $i++)
{
    $id = unique_id();
    if (in_array($id, $arr))
    {
        echo $id."\n";
        break;
    }
    $arr[]= $id;
}

echo "Generated ".count($arr)." unique IDs.\n";
```

Note that this only works if you need all those IDs in **one** request / script execution. A new request would cause the static `$counter` variable to start anew, which doesn't guarantee unique ids anymore.